# Sqlmap, using technique

Tags: sqlmap

In sqlmap I want to use `time-based blind` sqli technique. `--technique=` comes with a default of `BEUSTQ` which letter should use for time based blind only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think u should have a cookie for sql time-based blind .

For example tihs

`sqlmap -u 'http://192.168.85.129/vulnerabilities/sqli_blind/?id=&Submit=Submit' --cookie="PHPSESSID=1k37fvfqn08c82ua7qrgvp3su4; security=low" --dump --users --passwords`

or this is for --technique=BEUSTQ .

```
--banner --technique=BEUSTQ --level=1,2,3,4,5
```

GET and POST parameters are always tested, HTTP Cookie header values are tested from level 2 HTTP User-Agent/Referer headers' value is tested from level 3. `--risk=1,2,3,4` The default value is 1 which is innocuous for the majority of SQL injection points. Risk value 2 adds to the default level the tests for heavy query time-based SQL injections and value 3 adds also OR- based SQL injection tests. `--second-order=visible_page_url Injection`

Answer (score 12):

Accepted answer seems incorrect from my point of view. For a time based blind SQL injection, you should use letter `T`, for example `--technique=T` .

The list of techniques with its letters is as follows:

- B: Boolean-based blind
- E: Error-based
- U: Union query-based
- S: Stacked queries
- T: Time-based blind
- Q: Inline queries